# How to find markers near user current location in swift using google Map API

Tags: swift, google-maps-api-3

I have a number of marker coordinates stored in array. I want to be able to locate the markers that are near the user on the map. For example there are 3 markers near user. I know that google supply a distance matrix api which calculate the distance (2min from user). the only solution i found was in javascript. If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `distance(from location: CLLocation)` of `CLLocation` class. Its in `CLLocation` class

```
open func distance(from location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance
```

> Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.

Here is the Apple's [Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance)

Usage

> **Swift 3.x code**

let us assume there is a variable of `CLLocation` called `userLocation` in which the lat and long of user location is there. So to calculate the distance from `userLocation` to your `markerLocation` and there is an object called `marker` of `GMSMarker` class

```
let markerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude)
let metres = userLocation.distance(from: markerLocation)
print(metres) //will be in metres
```

Here you will get the distance between your `marker` position and your `userLocation`. So you can write your logic accordingly.