# iOS Google Maps search list of markers within radius

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to implement a search where I can search markers that are inside user's location region (user location is the centered and ranges from there).

I looked through the documentation in google maps and I encounter a [GMSProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection) but I don't understand the implementation. I also tried this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099799/how-to-find-markers-near-user-current-location-in-swift-using-google-map-api) but not luck.

Anyone would like to help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

google maps offers a places api where you can define a radius for searching and filter word to get the data . it even support auto complete

check this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Comment: Do you have a sample code on how to use google places?

Comment: Also I want **markers** only to be searched not places :)